# How to capture serverless website screenshot using AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

How to run an AWS Lambda function on a regular basis that saves screenshot of the webpage of a given specific URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "a snapshot of website"? Where is the website currently running? Are you simply wanting a place to backup files?

Comment: snap shot means I want to get screenshot of an instance of a website and I want this service to run on AWS lambda

Comment: Aha! So, your requirement is actually: "Run an AWS Lambda function on a regular basis that navigates through every page of a given website, saving a screenshot of each page"? If so, could you please update your question to reflect this requirement?

Comment: actually not of every web pages. I want screen shot of the specific url that is given.

Comment: You might be able to use a scraping tool or a testing tool (eg Selenium) to capture screenshots of a website. I've also heard of people using a "headless browser" within Lambda.

Answer (score 4):

Because your question is so generic - I'm just going to provide you the resources that I used to produce a similar lambda function for myself.

Getting puppeteer into Lambda
https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda

Taking screenshots in Puppeteer
https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-take-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-puppeteer/

Then just run your job on a cron or queue it up however you would like and then dump the screenshot into S3

Good luck!

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: none of this works